# Change local based on object

Tags: django, django-i18n

I work on a website that needs to differentiate UK english and US english. The distinction we try to make is not **per session** but rather **per object**.

e.g.

We have a UK `dog` and a US `cat`, the UK `dog` costs `£1` and the US `cat` `$2`.

The stored value of the cost is `1` and `2` and both object have a `locale` value: `uk` / `us`.

---

We already tried to add a middleware to switch the locale depending on the request. But having to fetch the object (based on the url's parameters) seems excessive.

Another idea was to add a `?locale=xx` to each url, but it's not ideal, since the information is already stored on the object.

---

Is there a way to use the django i18n mechanism to handle the translation between languages **per object**?

Meaning if the `object.locale` is `uk` render `£`, if it's `us` render `$`.

Comment: Must it be a Django i18n mechanism?

Comment: If possible yes, it would be the easier to handle. But it seems it's not possible so we're open to any workaround.

Answer (score 1):

If this is an object-by-object attribute, you could store it as an attribute of the model itself and access it with instance.__class__.locale. You could also do type(instance).locale or instance._meta.model.locale

```
class Dog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=127, default='rover')
    cost = models.IntegerField()
    locale = "uk"

class Cat(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=127, default='fluffy')
    cost = models.IntegerField()
    locale = "us"
```

Or if able to access it from the instance itself, it's even simpler: instance.locale

If there's added functionality you're hoping to get out of i18n (perhaps in the template) you could pass in a context variable or store that as an attribute of a class-based view.

Comment: I see, we just don't want to have a condition for each amount/currency to display either pounds or dollars. This is why we thought about the i18n functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't see how you could use i18n to resolve your problem.

Alternatively, this doesn't use Django i18n but it should work

You could set this up in your `settings.py`:

```
CURRENCY = {
    'uk': '£',
    'us': '$',
}
```

Then to get the correct currency you can do:

```
settings.CURRENCY[object.locale]
```

You could even go further and wrap this in a model property

```
@property
def currency(self):
   return settings.CURRENCY[self.locale]
```